# what is the best way to move the elements: the whole vector or move + erase for the elements?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how best to move elements from one vector to another .Let's say you can do this :

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5);
std::vector<int> move_v = std::move(v);
```

And then everything works as I thought: `std::size(v)` prints 0, and in another vector the elements appeared. On the other hand.

I have seen that it is often suggested to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::vector<int> move_v(10);
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5);

std::move(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(move_V));
v.erase(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

But it doesn't work quite as well as I expect.Why are the elements after `std::move` not moved here,that is, here the elements in the vector v remain in place.And we need to call the `erase` function .Are they being moved or are they being copied?Actually, I wonder which approach is considered better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you're moving the whole vector at once. This is presumably what you want. Just copy a couple of pointers, you're done. O(1) complexity and everything is good.

In the second example, you're moving every element individually. This means that you're trying to move integers, which is the same as copying. So, no moving takes place. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: And if in the general case?that is, there will be some kind of custom data type, not int?

Comment: If you have a class, like `std::string`, all those elements will be moved. Still probably not what you want.

Comment: That is, it turns out better to always use 1 method?

Comment: @Omegon In this specific case, yes. The 1st method may not be an option if you are moving elements within the same container, etc. In that case you have to do the second.